# Import default in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**person.js**

```
export default class Person {
    // code...
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Person from './person';
```

**When run main.js i got an error**

```
import Person from './person';
       ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

*Thanks*

Comment: You need the `.mjs` extension and the experimental modules flag in all but maybe the latest versions of node. This also means you are forced to use the extension of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Node has experimental support for ECMAScript Modules:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

If you insist on using that syntax, rename files with `.mjs` extension, instead of `.js` and run node with `--experimental-modules` flag, like this:

```sh
node --experimental-modules main.mjs
```

Using Node.js v12+, you can keep `.js` file extensions if you set `"type": "module"` in `package.json` file, in which case command to run it will be:

```sh
node --experimental-modules main.js
```